# In Magento 2 :- How to give return functionality of rma-graphql module for guest users

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, magento2.4.6, magento-graphql

I want to give the return functionality for the guest users in rma-graphql default module.

Also, I want to revoke the customer access token for the guest users in rma-graphql default module.

If anyone has a solution please update here.

Thanks in advance